# node sass can I @import './directory/**/*.scss'?

Tags: node-sass

Can I import all `.scss` files in a sub-directories with node-sass?

I'm guessing it would be something like this?

```
@import './directory/**/*.scss'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is a request on the Ruby Sass GitHub repository for this functionality, but libsass/node-sass won't implement functionality not in the main language. You may be able to find plugins that do this.